# JavaScript: Display next index of words after all words on previous array have been typed

Tags: javascript

I'm making a game where an array of words are animated from top of the page to bottom of the page and the user has to type all of the words before they reach the bottom. I'm stuck on changing the set of words after all the words on one set have been typed. Here is my code.

JS:

```
var word = ""; // what the user types
var targets = [["hey", "sup", "nothing", "memories", "man"], ["next", "level"]]; // array of words
var wordTyped = document.getElementById("wordtyped"); // div where it shows what the user typed
var wordlist = document.getElementById("wordlist"); // div where the array of words are displayed
var arrindex = 0;

// display the words in a div called indword. erase the current wordlist, update it with the new wordlist.
function displayWords(arr) {
    wordlist.innerHTML = "";
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        wordlist.innerHTML += "<div class='indword'>"+arr[i]+"</div>";
        wordlist.innerHTML += "   ";
    }
}


// this is the game loop
function gameloop(arrindex) {

    displayWords(targets[arrindex]); // initially display all the words in     the array

    // listen for typing events
    document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

        word += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // this is what the user types
        wordTyped.innerHTML = word; // show what the user is typing on the div
        console.log(word);

        // this whole thing is to check if the word that the user typed is in the array targets
        var index = targets[arrindex].indexOf(word); 

        if (index > -1) {
            console.log("success");

            targets[arrindex].splice(index, 1); // if what the user types exists in targets, delete that from the array

            displayWords(targets[arrindex]); // then remove the existing array and display the new array.
            word = ""; // reset user input
            wordTyped.innerHTML = word;
        }

    });
}

gameloop(arrindex);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="wordlist" class="godown"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the whole thing.
http://codepen.io/davegumba/pen/OXMKOj

I've tried wrapping the gameloop in a closure like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    (function gameloop(arrindex) {...
    })(i);
}
```

But it goes straight to the last index of the array, and also it duplicates all the letters I type, so typing the word "next" would instead output "nneexxtt". How do I fix this?

Comment: For the typing error, change the keypress event for the keyup event (probably you're getting keydown and keyup events triggering the call. The part of the "whole set have been typed", i think you could simply ease the word once it's used, and then just check if the array is empty to switch to the next array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a couple ways.

use a pointer, and then update the pointer when you complete part of it.

```
var pointer = 0;
//when work is matched, remove it from the array, and when that array is empty, increment the pointer
if(arr[pointer].length == 0){
    pointer++;
}
```

Or you use an array function like [array.shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift); which returns the first element of an array while removing it. so each time your working array of works is empty, shift to the next one.

```
var targets = [["one", "two", "three"], ["four","five","six"]];
var arr = targets.shift(); //now ["one", "two", "three"];

//when matched a word in the list.. trigger this function
function matchedWord(typedWord){
   arr.splice(arr.indexOf(typedWord),1);

   if(arr.length == 0){
     if(targets.length>0)
       arr = targets.shift(); //now ["four", "five", "six"]
     } else { 
       //you win
     }
   }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.